# Slider scrolls the page to the top when slide (only in mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I have recently used a slider on my site , when I tried to check responsive (chrome) the slider scrolls up to itself when it slides the img. Wherever you are at the page, it automatically scrolls a little bit until reaching the slider. The slider isn't interactive. ( I am barely new at coding ).

`HTML

```
 
        <div class="slider-container">
            <div class="slider" id="slider" >
                <div class="slider__section" >
                    <img class="slider__img" src="/Muestra/rerereressssss.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__section">
                    <img class="slider__img" src="/Muestra/Mumbai-restaurant-COVID-19-1366x7689.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__section">
                    <img class="slider__img" src="/Muestra/fenaceeooswww.png" alt="">
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </div>
```

`CSS

```
.slider-container{
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
}

.slider {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 300%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left : -100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;

}

.slider__section {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.slider__img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

`JS

```
const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
let sliderSection = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__section");
let sliderSectionLast = sliderSection[sliderSection.length -1];

slider.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin',sliderSectionLast);

function moveRight() {

    let sliderSectionFirst = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__section")[0];
    
   

    slider.style.marginLeft = "-200%";
    slider.style.transition = "all 0.5s";
    setTimeout(function(){

        slider.style.transition = "none";
        slider.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',sliderSectionFirst);
        slider.style.marginLeft = "-100%";

       
        
    }, 500 );

    


}

function moveLeft() {

    let sliderSectionLast= document.querySelectorAll(".slider__section")[3];
    slider.style.marginLeft = "0";
    slider.style.transition = "all 0.5s";
    setTimeout(function(){

        slider.style.transition = "none";
        slider.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin',sliderSectionLast);
        slider.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
    }, 500 );


}

setInterval(function(){
    console.log(sliderSectionLast);
},4500 );


setInterval(function(){
    moveRight();
},4500 );
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't saw the problem that you have mentioned.

But, when I run your code I see that it looks like you forgot to add `left` property to the slider container, because of this the image doesn't fit the slider container in the left side.
try this:

```
.slider {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 300%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left : -100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I checked other navigators and I realized that it only happens in Chrome. I want to clarify the issue: Each time the slider changes the slide, the page scrolls up to itself